# Cannot get full screen plots with Bokeh tabs / panels

Tags: python, bokeh, graphing

Haven't been able to find an example of tab layouts in Bokeh that I desire.

I have something that looks like the example: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html#tab-panes

However, I'd like to have the plots be able to 'expand' with the screen, ie have something like `sizing_mode =` scale_width, scale_height or stretch_both. I've tried playing with the toy tabs example that I posted above but cannot seem to get the plots to change size or I get a `Bokeh Error unsatisfiable constraints`.

Anyone have luck on making a panel layout with full screen plots?